# sum up the series $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1 } \cos n x /\sqrt{n}$ numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, convergence-acceleration

For $x$ close to zero, the series converge slowly.

Is there a way to accelerate the convergence?

Comment: There is an explicit solution using polylogarithm functions.

Comment: Yes, but to calculate the polylogarithm function we also need tricks.

Comment: For $x\to 0$ you could use the asymptotic expression $\frac{3 x^2 \zeta \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{32 \pi ^2}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{\sqrt{x}}+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. May I ask where you did find it ? It is very nice. Thanks.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici This is just the series expansion of $\Re(\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(e^{-i x}\right))$ which is the exact expression of the infinite sum, as you mentioned before.

Comment: But the asymptotic expression is not necessarily sufficient for a specific value of $x $.

Comment: I tried Matlab. It can deal with integer-order polylogs.